# How do I create an array of parcelable objects?

Tags: android, parcelable

I have an object that implements Parcelable and I am trying to create an array of that object. However, whenever I change one of the elements in the array, all other elements in the array also are changed to the same value.

When I create an array like this and then set the first element,

```
MyClass[] array = new myClass[5];
array[0] = new MyClass();
```

all the elements in the array will take on the value of array[0]. Is this a property of Parcelable objects and that I am just doing things wrong? Is there a method I am supposed to be using instead?

Comment: A parcelable object is one that need to know how to be serialized and de-serialized if you are creating your own class, then your classes need to know how to be parcellable, which would require a custom object that can serialize/de-serialize the array. Should begin by checking where you need to serialize based on missing abilities of some of your super classes like ArrayList.

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong, Parcelable doesn't alter the behavior of the class, it only provides a way to persist/communicate the object between Android process. Can you share the way you are putting the element into the array?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the parcelable issue, you are assigning same object at all the array indexes, you are **not creating new MyClass() object**.

In case you want to change each array object independently, ***you have to create a new object by calling constructor or clone the first one to create a new object***.

Example: this example can be used as a reference.

```
MyClass[] array = new myClass[5];
array[0] = new MyClass();
array[1] = new MyClass();
array[2] = new MyClass();
array[3] = new MyClass();
array[4] = new MyClass();
```

Comment: What do you suggest on how to initialize the `array` variable?

Comment: i have added simplified example